# Looking inside a QStringList for duplicate strings and getting a count of duplicates

Tags: c++, qt

Is there a way to get the amount of times a duplicate string is in a QStringList and group it with the string itself?

For example, if a list contains [" a ", " a ", " a ",  "a ", " b ", " b ", " b ", " c ", " c "]

would I be able to turn it into something like

a x4

b x3

c x2

My only solution right now is to use `QList::contains()` and then adding them up with ints but the problem with that is there are 500 strings that can go into the QStringList so I don't want to have to create 500 strings with 500 ints.

Comment: Are strings always grouped like in your example?

Comment: You could sort the list and then iterate through it while tracking if the string at your current index changes or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
QMap<QString,int> countOfStrings;
QStringList listOfStrings;
listOfStrings<<"a"<<"b"<<"c"<<"a";
for(int i=0;i<listOfStrings.count();i++)
{
    countOfStrings[listOfStrings[i]]++;
}
```

`QMap` defaults `int`s to 0.If it comes up with a string for the first time,it automatically creates an entry with `(newStr,0)` by invoking `countOfStrings[newStr]`

You can also do `qDebug()<<countOfStrings;`

Comment: In C++11, the loop should be written as `for (auto const &str : listOfStrings) countOfStrings[str]++;`

Comment: @MuhammetAliAsan, if an organisation doesn't use C++, then they don't have to use Kuba's suggestion. As I see it, he's just providing additional information, rather than criticising your answer. If he thought you were wrong, he could have posted his own answer, or even edit yours.